# Is it true that $\iint_{x^2+y^2 \le 1} f(ax+by+c) dx dy=2 \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-u^2}f(u\sqrt{a^2+b^2} +c)du $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Is it true that $\iint_S f(ax+by+c) dx dy=2 \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-u^2}f(u\sqrt{a^2+b^2} +c)du $  ?

where $S:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2+y^2 \le 1\}$

I know I need to do a change of variable , but I don't know what change of variable .

Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, Saun Dev. I see that you've had quite a few downvoted posts recently; this is likely due to the fact that your questions are generally missing context or details. What have you tried, and where are you having trouble? What is the motivation for your question? What techniques do you know that might be relevant here? Have you ever seen a similar problem? Please do not just post bare questions.

Comment: I have tried to do the $x=r\cos t ; y=r\sin t$ transformation without getting anywhere ; please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: You can change variable to 
$$\begin{cases}
u &= \frac{ax + by}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\\
v &= \frac{-bx + ay}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
x &= \frac{au - bv}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\\
y &= \frac{bu + av}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
\end{cases}
$$
This is a rotation with respect to origin which bring the $x$-axis into the direction $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it is true. Equating the arguments of $f$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
ax+by+c&=u\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+c\\
\frac{ax+by}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}&=u
\end{align*}

> This suggests a *transformation by rotation* according to the comment of @achillehui
>   \begin{align*}
> u=\frac{ax+by}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\qquad&\qquad x=\frac{au-bv}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\\
> \tag{1}\\
> v=\frac{-bx+ay}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\qquad&\qquad y=\frac{bu+av}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
> \end{align*}

In order to transform the integral
\begin{align*}
\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq 1}f(ax+by+c)\,dx\,dy
\end{align*}

we first consider the transformation of the disc $x^2+y^2\leq 1$. Since the transformation is a rotation we expect as result the unit disc in the variables $u$ and $v$.

> We obtain using (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> x^2+y^2&=
> \frac{(au-bv)^2}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{(bu+av)^2}{a^2+b^2}\\
> &=\frac{(a^2u^2-2abuv+b^2v^2)+(b^2u^2+2abuv+a^2v^2)}{a^2+b^2}\\
> &=u^2+v^2
> \end{align*}

We need the *[Jacobian determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)*
$\frac{\partial(x,u)}{\partial(u,v)}$
in order to transform the integral:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial(x,u)}{\partial(u,v)}&=\begin{vmatrix}x_u&x_v\\y_u&y_v\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}&\frac{-b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\\
\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}&\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}\begin{vmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{vmatrix}\\
&=1
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \iint_{x^2+y^2\leq 1}&f(ax+by+c)\,dx\,dy=\\
> &=\iint_{u^2+v^2\leq 1}f(u\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+c)\frac{\partial(x,u)}{\partial(u,v)}\,du\,dv\\
> &=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-u^2}}^{\sqrt{1-u^2}}f(u\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+c)\,dv\,du\\
> &=\int_{-1}^{1}f(u\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+c)\left(\int_{-\sqrt{1-u^2}}^{\sqrt{1-u^2}}1\,dv\right)\,du\\
> &=2\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1-u^2}f(u\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+c)\,du\\
> \end{align*}

Comment: @SaunDev: Thanks a lot for accepting my answer and granting the bounty! Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Draw a properly scaled $u$-axis in direction of the vector $(a,b)$ trough the origin, and consider the line $\ell_u$ which  intersects this axis orthogonally at $u$. If $-1\leq u\leq 1$ this line intersects the disk $x^2+y^2\leq1$ in a segment of length $2\sqrt{1-u^2}$. As $\ell_u$ is orthogonal to $(a,b)$ the linear function $(x,y)\mapsto ax+by+c$ is constant along $\ell_u$, and this constant value is easily seen to be $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\,u +c$.
It is then geometrically obvious that
$$\int_{x^2+y^2\leq1} f(ax+by+c)\>{\rm d}(x,y)=2\int_{-1}^1 f\bigl(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}u +c\bigr)\>\sqrt{1-u^2}\>du\ .$$